# Подгон размеров div блоков под экран

Tags: javascript

Всем привет! Как реализовать изменение размеров блока при изменении размеров экрана? На сайте http://agar.io это реализовано так, что блок не может выйти за пределы размеров экрана. Буду рад готовым скриптам.

Answer (score 0):

В css можно указывать свойства такие как : width, height... в процентах от размера родительского блока, если родительским блоком является , то размер дочернего блока будет равен указанному проценту от размеров окна браузера.
В js можно узнать размеры окна с помощью `document.documentElement.clientWidth` для ширины и `documentElement.clientHeight` для высоты.